# React Typescript Order Form calculation error on change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, async-await, react-redux

I'm building an order form using react typescript. The form allows the user to input the `quantity`, `unit price`, and to select whether or not the item is `taxable`.

I stripped down my code for this example to only show the ability to add 1 or 2 items. But for the final product he user will be able to add about 10-15 items. So there will be 15 of each field. Which will be labeled as `quantity1`, `quantity2`, `quantity3`, and etc.

So once the user selects the quantity, unit price, and if the item is taxable or not. I have a field which calculates the `total extended price` which is just the `quantity * unit price`

I also have two fields. One which adds all of taxes for all items (which are just the ones where the user selects taxable to yes). And the other is the total price with all taxes.

Everything works right now. But below are the 3 problems I'm facing. The problems start when a user makes a change.

- if a user selects `taxable` to `Yes` and then back to `No`. The price adjusts however the `Estimated Sales Tax` still doesn't reflect the change.
- If a user selects 5 as the quantity then changes to 4, back to 5, the tax gets added twice.
- If the tax ends up being a decimal when adding the tax to the total amount the math is wrong.

Here is my code:

```
import * as React from 'react';

export class Screen1 extends React.Component<{}, {
    Quantity: number, 
    UnitPrice: number,
    ExtendedPrice: number,
    Taxable1: string,
    TaxAmount1: number,
    Quantity2: number, 
    UnitPrice2: number,
    ExtendedPrice2: number,
    Taxable2: string,
    TaxAmount2: number,
    EstimatedTotal: number;
    EstimatedSalesTax: number;
}> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Quantity: null,
            UnitPrice: null,
            ExtendedPrice: null,
            Taxable1: '',
            TaxAmount1: null,
            Quantity2: null,
            UnitPrice2: null,
            ExtendedPrice2: null,
            Taxable2: '',
            TaxAmount2: null,                   
            EstimatedTotal: null,
            EstimatedSalesTax: 0,                       
        };

        this.handleChangeQuantity = this.handleChangeQuantity.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeUnitPrice = this.handleChangeUnitPrice.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeExtendedPrice = this.handleChangeExtendedPrice.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeTaxable1 = this.handleChangeTaxable1.bind(this);

        this.handleChangeEstimatedTotal = this.handleChangeEstimatedTotal.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeEstimatedSalesTax = this.handleChangeEstimatedSalesTax.bind(this);

    }


    handleChangeQuantity = async (event: any) => {
        const value = parseInt(event.target.value)
        await this.setState({ Quantity: value })
        console.log(value);
        this.handleChangeExtendedPrice()
      }

    handleChangeUnitPrice = async (event: any) => {
        const value = parseInt(event.target.value)
        await this.setState({ UnitPrice: value })
        console.log(value);
        this.handleChangeExtendedPrice()
    }

    handleChangeTaxable1 = async (event: any) => {
        const value = event.target.value;
        await this.setState({ Taxable1: value })
        console.log(value);
        this.handleChangeExtendedPrice()
    }

    handleChangeExtendedPrice() {
        if (this.state.Taxable1 === "Yes") {
            this.setState({ 
                ExtendedPrice: (this.state.Quantity * this.state.UnitPrice) + ((this.state.Quantity * this.state.UnitPrice) * .08),
                TaxAmount1: (this.state.Quantity * this.state.UnitPrice) * .08
            }); 
        } else {
            this.setState({ 
                ExtendedPrice: this.state.Quantity * this.state.UnitPrice,
            }); 
        }
        console.log(this.state.ExtendedPrice);
        this.handleChangeEstimatedTotal();      
    }

    handleChangeEstimatedSalesTax = async () => {
        await this.setState({ 
            EstimatedSalesTax: this.state.TaxAmount1 + this.state.TaxAmount2,
        }); 
        console.log(this.state.EstimatedSalesTax);      
    }   

    handleChangeEstimatedTotal = async () => {
        await this.setState({ 
            EstimatedTotal: this.state.ExtendedPrice + this.state.ExtendedPrice2 + this.state.EstimatedSalesTax,
        }); 
        console.log(this.state.EstimatedTotal);
        this.handleChangeEstimatedSalesTax();
    }


    public render(): React.ReactElement<{}> {

        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this._onNewRequest}>

                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <label>
                                Quantity <br /> (Units)
                            </label>
                            <input
                                value={this.state.Quantity}
                                onChange={this.handleChangeQuantity}
                                type="number"
                                maxLength={9}
                                pattern='[0-9]{0,5}'
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>
                                Estimated<br /> Unit Price
                            </label>
                            <input
                                value={this.state.UnitPrice}
                                onChange={this.handleChangeUnitPrice}
                                type="number"
                                pattern='[0-9]{0,5}'
                                prefix={'$'}                                            
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>
                                Estimated<br /> Extended Price
                            </label>
                            <input
                                value={this.state.ExtendedPrice}
                                //onChange={(e) => this.handleChangeUnitPrice(e)}
                                type="number"
                                disabled
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>
                                Taxable?
                            </label>
                            <select name="Taxable1" value={this.state.Taxable1} onChange={this.handleChangeTaxable1}> 
                                <option value="No">No</option>
                                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>                            
                            </select>
                        </div>                                                                      
                    </div>


                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <label>
                                Estimated Sales Tax
                            </label>
                            <input
                                value={this.state.EstimatedSalesTax}
                                type="number"
                                disabled
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>
                                Estimated Total
                            </label>
                            <input
                                value={this.state.EstimatedTotal}
                                type="number"
                                disabled
                            />
                        </div>                                                                              
                    </div>                                                                                              

                </form>

        );
    }
}
```

Comment: You should not be awaiting `setState`. If you want to do something after its updated you can use the callback style


`this.setState({ Quantity: value }, this.handleChangeExtendedPrice);`

Comment: @topched when I remove the awaiting. Since the for the tax. It then does it on load. So before the quantity and unit price can be filled. it will say my tax is 0.8. Hard to explain. I'm not the best at react either.

Comment: Hard to tell whats going on. Remove all the async and await key words, then use the callback style for running actions after the state is updated. Just note when you do setState() then console.log(this.state) there is no guarantee that this.state is updated at that point. State updates are NOT synchronous they are scheduled by react and can be batched

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is will fix your problems :

```
export class Screen1 extends React.Component<{}, {
    Quantity: number, 
    UnitPrice: number,
    ExtendedPrice: number,
    Taxable1: string,
    TaxAmount1: number,
    Quantity2: number, 
    UnitPrice2: number,
    ExtendedPrice2: number,
    Taxable2: string,
    TaxAmount2: number,
    EstimatedTotal: number;
    EstimatedSalesTax: number;
}> {

    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Quantity: null,
            UnitPrice: null,
            ExtendedPrice: null,
            Taxable1: '',
            TaxAmount1: null,
            Quantity2: null,
            UnitPrice2: null,
            ExtendedPrice2: null,
            Taxable2: '',
            TaxAmount2: null,                   
            EstimatedTotal: null,
            EstimatedSalesTax: 0,                       
        };

        this.handleChangeQuantity = this.handleChangeQuantity.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeUnitPrice = this.handleChangeUnitPrice.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeExtendedPrice = this.handleChangeExtendedPrice.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeTaxable1 = this.handleChangeTaxable1.bind(this);

        this.handleChangeEstimatedTotal = this.handleChangeEstimatedTotal.bind(this);
        this.handleChangeEstimatedSalesTax = this.handleChangeEstimatedSalesTax.bind(this);

    }


    handleChangeQuantity = async (event: any) => {
        const value = parseInt(event.target.value)
        await this.setState({ Quantity: value })
        console.log(value);
        this.handleChangeExtendedPrice()
      }

    handleChangeUnitPrice = async (event: any) => {
        const value = parseInt(event.target.value)
        await this.setState({ UnitPrice: value })
        console.log(value);
        this.handleChangeExtendedPrice()
    }

    handleChangeTaxable1 = async (event: any) => {
        const value = event.target.value;
        await this.setState({ Taxable1: value })
        console.log(value);
        this.handleChangeExtendedPrice()
    }

    handleChangeExtendedPrice() {
        if (this.state.Taxable1 === "Yes") {
            this.setState({ 
                ExtendedPrice: (this.state.Quantity * this.state.UnitPrice),
                TaxAmount1: (this.state.Quantity * this.state.UnitPrice) * .08
            }); 
        } else {
            //***You must reset TaxAmount1...
            this.setState({ 
                ExtendedPrice: this.state.Quantity * this.state.UnitPrice,
                TaxAmount1: 0
            }); 
        }
        console.log(this.state.ExtendedPrice);
        this.handleChangeEstimatedTotal();      
    }

    handleChangeEstimatedSalesTax = async () => {
        await this.setState({ 
            EstimatedSalesTax: this.state.TaxAmount1 + this.state.TaxAmount2,
        }); 
        console.log(this.state.EstimatedSalesTax);      
    }   

    handleChangeEstimatedTotal = async () => {
        //***first calculate tax then calculate the total...
        await this.handleChangeEstimatedSalesTax();

        await this.setState({ 
            EstimatedTotal: this.state.ExtendedPrice + this.state.ExtendedPrice2 + this.state.EstimatedSalesTax,
        }); 

        console.log(this.state.EstimatedTotal);

    }


    public render(): React.ReactElement<{}> {

        return (
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this._onNewRequest}>

                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <label>
                                Quantity <br /> (Units)
                            </label>
                            <input
                                value={this.state.Quantity}
                                onChange={this.handleChangeQuantity}
                                type="number"
                                maxLength={9}
                                pattern='[0-9]{0,5}'
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>
                                Estimated<br /> Unit Price
                            </label>
                            <input
                                value={this.state.UnitPrice}
                                onChange={this.handleChangeUnitPrice}
                                type="number"
                                pattern='[0-9]{0,5}'
                                prefix={'$'}                                            
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>
                                Estimated<br /> Extended Price
                            </label>
                            <input
                                value={this.state.ExtendedPrice}
                                //onChange={(e) => this.handleChangeUnitPrice(e)}
                                type="number"
                                disabled
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>
                                Taxable?
                            </label>
                            <select name="Taxable1" value={this.state.Taxable1} onChange={this.handleChangeTaxable1}> 
                                <option value="No">No</option>
                                <option value="Yes">Yes</option>                            
                            </select>
                        </div>                                                                      
                    </div>


                    <div>
                        <div>
                            <label>
                                Estimated Sales Tax
                            </label>
                            <input
                                value={this.state.EstimatedSalesTax}
                                type="number"
                                disabled
                            />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <label>
                                Estimated Total
                            </label>
                            <input
                                value={this.state.EstimatedTotal}
                                type="number"
                                disabled
                            />
                        </div>                                                                              
                    </div>                                                                                              

                </form>
                </div>

        );
    }
}


render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

#### Changes I Have Made:

1.) In `handleChangeExtendedPrice()` I have changed else condition as TaxAmount1 must reset to 0, this might be the reason for changes not reflecting...

```
handleChangeExtendedPrice() {
        if (this.state.Taxable1 === "Yes") {
            this.setState({ 
                ExtendedPrice: (this.state.Quantity * this.state.UnitPrice),
                TaxAmount1: (this.state.Quantity * this.state.UnitPrice) * .08
            }); 
        } else {
            //***You must reset TaxAmount1...
            this.setState({ 
                ExtendedPrice: this.state.Quantity * this.state.UnitPrice,
                TaxAmount1: 0
            }); 
        }
        console.log(this.state.ExtendedPrice);
        this.handleChangeEstimatedTotal();      
    }
```

2.) I have changed `handleChangeEstimatedTotal` to call this.handleChangeEstimateSalesTax() , because we must first calculate tax values and then proceed!

```
handleChangeEstimatedTotal = async () => {
        //***first calculate tax then calculate the total...
        await this.handleChangeEstimatedSalesTax();

        await this.setState({ 
            EstimatedTotal: this.state.ExtendedPrice + this.state.ExtendedPrice2 + this.state.EstimatedSalesTax,
        }); 

        console.log(this.state.EstimatedTotal);

    }
```

Doing this will hopefully solve your problems

Comment: Thank you!!! This worked like a charm. I'm going to look more into solution to get a better grasp. This definitely was helpful!

Comment: Thanks if you need any help plz ask.